# If $A$ Hurwitz, $(A+A^*)$ is Hurwitz?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hurwitz-matrices

If I have $A$ Hurwitz matrix, is $(A+A^*)$, with $A^*$ the transpose of $A$, still Hurwitz? Any reference or proof?

Because if $(A+A^*)$ is still Hurwitz I can say that it is even negative definite being symmetric and with real eigenvalues negative.

Comment: What is your definition of a Hurwitz matrix?  Is it the matrix constructed from the coefficients of a polynomial, or a matrix where every eigenvalue has strictly negative real part (Hurwitz stability matrix)?

Comment: Every eigenvalue has strictly negative real part.

Comment: $$A = \begin{pmatrix} -\varepsilon & 1\\ 0 & -\varepsilon\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @MTF The point is quite clear: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_matrix

Comment: I know what an Hurwitz matrix is...but wikipedia doesn not answer to my question. By the way I answered by myself with a counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the sum with adjoint (or, equivalently, the  symmetric/Hermitian part) of a Hurwitz matrix is not in general a Hurwitz matrix. An example was given by Daniel Fischer in comments, and it can look  like this: 
$$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 10 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
is Hurwitz (both eigenvalues are $-1$) but its sum with transpose is
$$\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 10 \\ 10 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$$
which is a symmetric matrix with negative determinant. Such a matrix has real eigenvalues of opposite signs.